# Let $X = \{ (x, \sin(1/x)) : 0 <x \leq 1 \} \cup \{ (0,y) : -1\leq y \leq 1\}$ and $Y = [0,1)$. Are $X$ and $X \times Y$ connected, compact?

Tags: general-topology

Consider  $X = \{ (x, \sin(1/x)) : 0 <x \leq 1 \} \cup \{ (0,y) : -1\leq y \leq  1\}$ as  a  subspace  of  $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $Y = [0,1)$ as a  subspace  of $\mathbb{R}$. Then which of these options are correct?

1. $X$ is  connected.
2. $X$ is  compact.
3. $X \times  Y$ (in  product topology)  is connected.
4. $X \times  Y$ (in  product topology)  is compact.

My answer  is  : option $1)$ and option $3)$ are true: by the  graph I can show it's connected.

Option $2)$ and option $4)$ are  false because the graph is unbounded so it  is not compact.

Is this correct? Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The space $X$ is  known as the **(closed) topologist's sine curve**. There are quite a number of posts in this forum.

Comment: Personally, I don't know what graph you're talking about, so I'd be skeptical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! $X$ is compact, The minimum bounded is $1$. For closedness, the second set is the set of limit points of the first one.

---

For connectedness of $X$, note that the first set, call $A$,  in $X$ is the continous image of $(0,1]$ under $x \mapsto \sin 1/x$ . Now $(0,1]$ is connected , so is its continuous image  $A$. Also $A$ is connected implies $\overline{A}$ is conneceted. But $\overline{A}=X$ and so $X$ is connected !

The latter two is easy to determine and it is left as an exercise to you :-)

Comment: thanks u  @Chinnaapparaj,,,got  its  now  in detail

Comment: You are welcome!